# Heroku app working then not working on repeat with 503 error

Tags: javascript, heroku

I deployed my app with Heroku and it was working on computer and phone, then it stops working, then it works....

Here is a capture of the heroku logs I'm getting. How do I fix this?

[image]

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email,
    },
  }).then((dbUserData) => {
    req.session.save(() => {
      req.session.user_id = dbUserData.id;
      req.session.username = dbUserData.username;
      req.session.loggedIn = true;

      res.json({ user: dbUserData, message: 'You are now logged in!' });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: can you please share your code for better understanding.

Comment: https://github.com/deannapi/tech-blog-mvc     https://deanna-mvc-tech-blog.herokuapp.com/

Comment: It is mainly happening because you are accessing id variable somewhere which is undefined or not having any value.

Comment: are you passing email and password in request body to this route api/user/login ?

Comment: are you passing arguments to this route?

Comment: in the logs, the "/api/user_routes.js:78" is line 8 in my snippet

Comment: this is the file path, i am talking about the API endpoint, because this endpoint require email and password to be sent to work.

Comment: at this line req.session.user_id = dbUserData.id: you are getting error, as this id is undefined. You can try change dbUserData.id to dbUserData._id

Comment: yes, but I don't know why it's not pulling in